# LLDB equivalent of gdb "directory" command for specifying source search path?

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, lldb

Looking for the lldb equivalent of the gdb "*directory*" command to add search paths for finding missing source code (or possibly similar functionality within xcode)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `target.source-map` setting allows you define a series of `a => b` path remappings in the debug session.  It's not identical to the gdb *dir* command, which is a list of directories to search for source files by base name, but you can solve the same problems with `source-map`.  Here's an example where I move a source file to a hidden directory after compiling:

```
% cd /tmp
% echo 'int main () { }' > a.c
% clang -g a.c
% mkdir hide
% mv a.c hide/
% xcrun lldb a.out
(lldb) settings set target.source-map /tmp /tmp/hide
(lldb) l -f a.c
   1    int main () { }
(lldb) br se -n main
Breakpoint created: 1: name = 'main', locations = 1
(lldb) r
Process 21674 launched: '/private/tmp/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 21674 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x0000000100000f49 a.out`main + 9 at a.c:1, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    #0: 0x0000000100000f49 a.out`main + 9 at a.c:1
-> 1    int main () { }
(lldb)
```

For more information about this setting, type `set list target.source-map` in lldb.  fwiw you might have discovered this in lldb by doing `apropos path` which will list all commands/settings that have the word *path* in the name/description.  Seeing that there was a setting by this name, you'd do `settings list` to see the list of settings and find out that it's filed under `target.`.

Comment: Jason, thanks for clarify the usage and supplying a good self-explanatory example! ("A picture is worth a thousand words" ;-) Hope you don't mind using this example as a suggestion to update the "GDB TO LLDB COMMAND MAP" (http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html). /Regards, Lars.

Comment: Yeah, the only problem is that target.source-map isn't really the same thing as dir; it's equivalent to gdb's pathname-substitutions setting.  pathname-substitutions was used by Xcode behind the scenes but users were not normally aware of it.  We'll need to add a command similar to gdb's dir command to lldb at some point.

Comment: About the only thing I miss from this answer, would be how to find what source path was used when building it. If I connect to a remote machine, I often don't know what path was used, I hope can ask lldb to show me in what path it wants to find the source files, so I can source-map it correctly.

Comment: Easiest way:  use `image lookup --verbose --address $pc` (or `im loo -va $pc` to get all the information about the place where you're currently executing.  You can give `image lookup` a function name or whatever, too.  You can use the python scripting interface to get the current stack frame's filename too with a line like `script print lldb.frame.GetCompileUnit().GetFileSpec()`.

Comment: If lldb can't find the file I need (e.g., `l foo.cc:1` says `error: Could not find source file "foo.cc".`) then what? gdb's `directory` made it easy to say *look here!*, but in lldb there doesn't seem to be a solution unless you know where it was trying to find the file so you can give the proper argument to `target.source-map`, but it doesn't tell you that either.

Comment: Use `source info`

Comment: That is, navigate to the frame with the file you want to map and run `source info`.  It will give you the full pathname of the original source file.

Comment: This is a bug because it doesn't work if the build files do no longer exist but a copy of the source is available.

Comment: ```(lldb) source info
error: No debug info for the selected frame.
```
Where does one go from here?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to make this work if the binary includes relative paths.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with `lldb` not being able to find your source files may be caused by flawed compilation process - i just spent several hours in attempt to find a `lldb` command to set path to sources by force but ended up discovering that i performed both actual compiling and linking with identical set of flags (`-Wall -Werror -Wextra -g`) in my `Makefile`... So compiler worked without warning and error messages despite errors (or warning treated as errors) actually existed. Fixing them fixed `lldb` workflow. Maybe developers should consider adding some warning (for newbies like me) in case program wasn't able to find sources (they were located in the very same directory in `src` folder).