# Why LLDB doesn't work with an absolute path to the file?

Tags: c, debugging, lldb

Let's say I have a `.c` file on my Macbook `~/github/leetcode/c/src/hello.c`.

After compile with `cc -g` command, I have a binary file at `~/github/leetcode/c/bin/hello.o`

Now I want to use **LLDB** to debug,

```
lldb ~/github/leetcode/c/bin/hello.o
```

it works,

```
(lldb) target create "/Users/Wei/github/leetcode/c/bin/DifferentWaysToAddParentheses.o"
Current executable set to '/Users/Wei/github/leetcode/c/bin/DifferentWaysToAddParentheses.o' (x86_64).
```

but when I try to add a break point,

```
breakpoint set --file "~/github/leetcode/c/src/DifferentWaysToAddParentheses.c" --line 10
```

it seems that the `.c` file can not be found,

```
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

but, when I simply use the file name without the path,

```
breakpoint set --file DifferentWaysToAddParentheses.c --line 10
```

now it works,

```
Breakpoint 2: where = DifferentWaysToAddParentheses.o`main + 44 at DifferentWaysToAddParentheses.c:10, address = 0x0000000100000dec
```

It really confused me! **Why LLDB can not work with the path?** **The second question is, how can LLDB find the file without the path?** Thx!

Comment: take a look here. Maybe this is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973633/lldb-equivalent-of-gdb-directory-command-for-specifying-source-search-path

Comment: seems you have the point. thx @mko XD

Comment: `~` is a shell function. LLDB is presumably using direct OS calls to open files, so in your case absolute path would be `/Users/Wei/github/leetcode/c/src/DifferentWaysToAddParentheses.c`.

Comment: thx @tgregory .