# Modify symbol file's reference to source code files

Tags: debugging, symbols, lldb, debug-symbols

I noticed that after moving a .sys symbol file to a different directory, lldb is no longer able to show source code when stepping through the program.

How do .sys files keep a reference to program source files internally? It seems to me it's using some kind of relative path reference to source code files.

Is there any way to edit a .sys file to point to correct source code path?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about editing the actual debug info, but lldb provides commands to remap from the original path to the current source location as described in this answer:

[LLDB equivalent of gdb "directory" command for specifying source search path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973633/lldb-equivalent-of-gdb-directory-command-for-specifying-source-search-path/12981205#12981205)